# Change Android v21 toolbar specific to each fragment of navigation drawer list item?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I am using Navigation Drawer in my App and therefore using fragments for each list item in the drawer. I tried to change the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` on navigating to each fragment of Navigation Drawer's list item, however it is coming below the already present activity's toolbar instead of replacing it which is what I want.

How do I replace the already present toolbar in `ActionBarActivity` with fragment's toolbar? Let me know your suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

Since toolbar is a view, you can set the visibility of the Activity's toolbar to hidden, before transition to any fragment.

`toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Then inside the fragment layout you can set Fragment specific toolbar and set it as the actionbar for that fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use [AppCompatActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html).

It doesn't have default toolbar, so you can call [setToolbar(Toolbar toolbar)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)) for each fragment.